# How to setup Webui for private pypi server?

Tags: python, pypi, pypiserver

I'm able to install and setup private pypi server , however it has no UI such as https://pypi.org/ where we can see list of projects and there corresponding readme.

Is there any way to setup Web UI for private pypi server ?